# How to pause a recursive function for 3 seconds in javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've already seen below referenced questions before writing this post.

[how-to-pause-a-settimeout-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626005/how-to-pause-a-settimeout-call)

[how-to-pause-a-settimeout-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604614/how-to-pause-a-settimeout-function)

[how-to-pause-a-function-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446688/how-to-pause-a-function-in-javascript)

[delay-running-a-function-for-3-seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951708/delay-running-a-function-for-3-seconds)

**Question**

I've below code on which I want after some time my setTimeout function is paused. Then re-continue.

```
 typingCallback(that) {
     let total_length = that.typewriter_text.length;
     let current_length = that.typewriter_display.length;
     if (that.rewind === false) 
     {
         if(total_length  == current_length) 
         {
             // Here I want to pause this function for 3 seconds
            clearTimeout(3000);
            that.rewind = true;
         }
         else
         {
             that.typewriter_display += that.typewriter_text[current_length];
             console.log('Loop#1: ' + that.typewriter_display + " " + 'Length' + current_length);
         }
      } 
      else if (that.rewind === true)
      {
          if(current_length == 0) 
          {    
              that.rewind = false;
          }
          else
          {
              that.typewriter_display = that.typewriter_display.slice(0, -1);
              console.log('Loop#2: ' + that.typewriter_display + " " + 'Length' + current_length);
          }
      }
      setTimeout(that.typingCallback, 75, that);
   }
```

Comment: Depend on your version of ECMAScript, use generators or async/await functions. First solution works with this library https://github.com/tj/co , see docs for details. Second solution is just `await delay(3000)`, where `delay` function is `function delay(count) { return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(count)) }`. In this case your function will be paused in terms of control flow logic.

Comment: Alternatively, if you just want `that.rewind` to be set 3 seconds later, you can do `setTimeout(() => { that.rewind = true; }, 3000);`

Comment: @NathanP. Really? Is that is too easy? How can I forget this. But thanks for your prompt response.

Comment: Herm, it won't pause the execution, your function will go through though, I didn't saw the recursive part first :/

Answer (score 1):

Basically a simple setTimeout should do it:

```
typingCallback(that) {
 let total_length = that.typewriter_text.length;
 let current_length = that.typewriter_display.length;
 if (that.rewind === false) 
 {
     if(total_length  == current_length) 
     {
         // Here I want to pause this function for 3 seconds
        setTimeout(that.typingCallback,3000,that);//simply set the 3 second timeout
        that.rewind = true;
        return;//dont forget to stop the function somewhere here. If not were having two recursive timeout chains... :/
     }
       //call directly
       setTimeout(that.typingCallback,75,that);// the regular timeout
```

Comment: My bad, I read it before the edits :|

Comment: @NathanP. no worries, we were both guessing and had a 50% chance to be right...

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
function live() { 
    if (dead) {
        return;
    }
    // do something when alive
    setTimeout(live,speed);
} 
live();
```

Hope this will work for you... :)